# ASP.NET 5 - Render just partial view on list item click

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have more partial views on the page. One contains the list of music(stored on Azure Storage) and an other the media player. I want to load just the media player partial view by clicking on an item from the list. I also have to pass data(in my case a link) to the controller. I've read about AJAX, but I didn't find an example when you select a list item and pass data too...Here is my list:

```
<ul style="list-style:none">
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <li>
        <p><a asp-controller="Music" asp-action="Play" asp-route-uri="@item.DownloadUri">@item.TitleOnView</a></p>
    </li>
}
```

and the controller:

```
public IActionResult Play(string uri)
{
    ViewData["uri"] = uri;
    return PartialView("_MediaPlayerPartial");
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, using jQuery ajax you can do that.

Give a css class to your links so that we can use that as the jQuery selector later.

```
<a asp-controller="Music" asp-action="Play" asp-route-uri="@item.DownloadUri"
                                                      class="myLink">@item.TitleOnView</a>
```

And now listen to the `click` event on this link and get the `href` attribute value of the clicked link and make an ajax call. You can use the jQuery `loa`d method to load the partial view content to your page.

```
$(function(){

   $("a.myLink").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#YourContainerToShowPartial").load($(this).attr("href"));
   });

});
```

Assuming `YourContainerToShowPartial` is the Id of a div in your page where you want to show the response from your Play action method.

```
<div id="YourContainerToShowPartial"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately I get the 404 error to this link(http://localhost:5000/Music/Play?uri=<attribute>). My "Play" Action returns "return PartialView("_MediaPlayerPartial");". So I do not really understand why is necessary the id to the <div>, because in the <div> is "@Html.Partial("_MediaPlayerPartial", ViewData["uri"])".

Comment: When you try to access the url directly on a browser, are you getting a 404 /

Comment: is url param value having `/` in the string ?

Comment: I am storing the music in Azure Storage. The uri doesn't containes '/' It changes to it's code: "%2F". And ':', "space" too.

Comment: Can you share the url it generated ( check view source) and share it as it is ?

Comment: The link looks like this: [link](https://musicdrive.azurewebsites.net/Music/Play?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmusicdrivestorage.blob.core.windows.net%2Fgseriousb%2FDen5ity%20-%205th%20Realm)

Comment: hmmm...Ok. I'll try to resolve it myself. Anyway thank You very much for your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104465/discussion-between-gseriousb-and-shyju).